# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined

Tags: jquery

I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'append')
```

my goal is triggering the icon picker function also change the input value at the same time.

my code:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
          $('.input1').iconpicker(".input1")
          .append( "<p>Test</p>" );
          $('#inputid2').iconpicker("#inputid2");
          $('.input3').iconpicker(".input3");
        });

 <input type="text" class="input1 input"/>
      <br/><br/>
      <h4>Value == Amazon</h4>
      <input type="text" class="input" id="inputid2" value="fa-amazon"/>
      <br/><br/>
      <h4>Just for fun</h4>
      <input type="text" class="input3 input"/>
      <br/><br/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue from the js file. I added my task into the function.

```
jQuery(this).addClass('selectedicon');
if (jQuery(selector).attr('class') == whichInputClass && jQuery(selector).attr('id') == whichInputId) {
    jQuery(selector).val('fa-'+getIconId).change();
    $('.input1').append( ('fa-'+getIconId) ); // I added this line
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to add the element index in jQuery as the selector return an array

```
 $('.input1')[0]
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: $(...)[0].iconpicker is not a function

 $('.input1')[0].iconpicker(".input1")
      .append( "<p>Test</p>" );